# AVR code for converting GPS coordinates to NMEA format

Tags: c++, c, gps, avr, nmea

I made an Android application that takes data from the GPS and sends it. It's picked up by aPC, and sent over USB to an AVR kit, which needs to convert the longitude, latitude format to NMEA format and return it back to USB. The message format is:

> latitude='23.353434333' and longitude='45.34333345'

I need to convert the above message using an ATmega32 to NMEA GPS format, but since I don't know AVR programming, can somebody suggest how I can do it or the code for above?

Comment: This is not a "write code for me" forum, but a place to ask specific, well-researched coding questions, on code you are working on.

Answer (score 2):

That you have no experience with AVR programming has nothing to do with implementing NMEA. Knowing C however would help ;)

Your given representation *latitude='23.353434333' and longitude='45.34333345'* is called **decimal degrees** (your example is missing the N/S and E/W indication).

I assume you are aware that NMEA is a protocol specification, not just a coordinate format. The NMEA standard uses the following coordinate notation in the datasets:

XXYY.ZZZZ

This can be directly represented in the **degrees minutes seconds** format like this:

XX°YY'(0.ZZZZ * 60)"

So the conversion between the two is trivial, as well as the conversion from **degrees minutes seconds** to **decimal degrees**:

decimal degrees = degrees + minutes/60 + seconds/3600

So in essence you just have to perform the given conversions in reverse and you get your NMEA coordinate format.

A NMEA dataset looks like this:

$GPRMC,162614,A,**5230.5900,N,01322.3900,E**,10.0,90.0,131006,1.2,E,A*13

I highlighted the coordinate information in bold. Implementing the conversion is nothing special, while implementing the NMEA protocol requires some additional reading about the implementation details.

Comment: If you are not familiar with micro controller/AVR programming at all, you will probably have to learn the basics first. Since you "made an android application", I assume that you have at least basic coding skills. If that is the case, it shouldn't be that hard to implement the above mentioned coordinate transformation. You have to go alone from here or ask a separate question ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
void Convert_NMEA_Decimal(void)
{
    char CDD[3] = {};
    char CSS[7] = {};
    float DD = 0.0;
    float SS = 0.0;
    float LatDec = 0.0;
    float LogDec = 0.0;
    //convert Latitude from NMEA DDSS.SSSS to decimal
    CDD[0] = gnss1.latitude[0]; CDD[1] = gnss1.latitude[1]; //Separete DD from DDSS.SSSS
    CSS[0] = gnss1.latitude[2]; CSS[1] = gnss1.latitude[3]; CSS[2] = gnss1.latitude[4]; //Separete SS.SSSS from DDSS.SSSS
    CSS[3] = gnss1.latitude[5]; CSS[4] = gnss1.latitude[6];
    CSS[5] = gnss1.latitude[7]; CSS[6] = gnss1.latitude[8];

    DD = strtod(CDD,NULL); //Convert CDD string to float (DD)
    SS = strtod(CSS,NULL); //Convert CSS string to float (SS)

    LatDec = (DD + (SS/60)); //Convert for NMEA to Decimal
//  if(gnss1.latitude[9] == 'N')
//  {
//      LatDec = LatDec * -1;
//  }

    //convert Longitude from NMEA DDDSS.SSSS to decimal
    CDD[0] = gnss1.longitude[0]; CDD[1] = gnss1.longitude[1]; CDD[2] = gnss1.longitude[2]; //Separete DDD from DDSS.SSSS
    CSS[0] = gnss1.longitude[3]; CSS[1] = gnss1.longitude[4]; CSS[2] = gnss1.longitude[5]; //Separete SS.SSSS from DDSS.SSSS
    CSS[3] = gnss1.longitude[6]; CSS[4] = gnss1.longitude[7];
    CSS[5] = gnss1.longitude[8]; CSS[6] = gnss1.longitude[9];

    DD = strtod(CDD,NULL); //Convert CDD string to float (DD)
    SS = strtod(CSS,NULL); //Convert CSS string to float (SS)

    LogDec = (DD + (SS/60)); //Convert for NMEA to Decimal
    if(gnss1.longitude[10] == 'S' || gnss1.longitude[10] == 'W') //if longitude S or W Latitude x -1
    {
        LogDec = LogDec * -1;
    }

    snprintf(gnss1.latitude, 10, "%f", LatDec); //Convert Float Latitude to String
    snprintf(gnss1.longitude, 11, "%f", LogDec);//Convert Float Longitude to String
}
```

Comment: gnss is an struct for GPS location data. Ej:  gnss.latitude = 1825.2545N ~ (DDSS.SSSS)N

Comment: CDD[0] = gnss1.latitude[0]; CDD[1] = gnss1.latitude[1]; //Separate DD from DDSS.SSSS { here we take the data directly from the gnss1.latitude array in positions 0 and 1 that in the NMEA protocol correspond to DD}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Isn't CDD[2] garbage? So strtod(CDD,NULL) could crash?

Answer (score -1):

Convert a NMEA decimal-decimal degree value into degrees/minutes/seconds
 First. convert the decimal-decimal value to a decimal:
 5144.3855 (ddmm.mmmm) = 51 44.3855 = 51 + 44.3855/60 = 51.7397583 degrees

Then convert the decimal to degrees, minutes seconds:
 51 degress + .7397583 * 60 = 44.385498 = 44 minutes 
 .385498 = 23.1 seconds
 Result: 51 44' 23.1"

Comment: private String decimalToDMS(double value) {
        String result = null;
        double degValue = value / 100;
        int degrees = (int) degValue;
        double decMinutesSeconds = ((degValue - degrees)) / .60;
        double minuteValue = decMinutesSeconds * 60;
        int minutes = (int) minuteValue;
        double secsValue = (minuteValue - minutes) * 60;
        result = degrees + "\u00B0" + " " + minutes + "' " + String.format("%.1f", secsValue) + "\" ";
        return result;
    }